# How to automatically advance to the next line after F9 in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, ide, spyder

Coming from RStudio, I'm familiar with the behavior of the cursor automatically moving to the next line after running the current line. I think this makes sense for data analysis. Does Spyder have something similar?

I'm familiar with the concept of cell and auto-advancing cell in Spyder. However, I want to maintain a pure Python script (that can be run with `python file.py`) for portability, and don't want to use something that only makes sense on Spyder.

Comment: I too, am from R and was staggered to find auto advance to next line is not a feature in Spyder. I have manged to find this guide
https://docs.spyder-ide.org/editor.html

namely, the #%% trick. However, I am still getting the error "unexpected EOF while parsing" as Spyder does not auto advance to next line(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have requested this feature on the Spyder github repository and it will be implemented in version 3.0 which will probably be released next month!

See here for more information: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3115

Comment: As an update, the v3 of Spyder now supports auto advance with F9!

Answer (score 2):

Spyder is an IDE. You can create a python script in the editor area, save it and run it using <kbd>F5</kbd>.

If you have a file in the editor area there isn't the concept of cell. You can create something similar. Have a look [here](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/editor.html?highlight=cell#how-to-define-a-code-cell). Once you have created some 'code cells' you can run these snippets using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A third option would be to use <kbd>F9</kbd> but you have to select the code you want to execute manually.

Comment: I want to be able to run several line of code interactively, so `F5` doesn't work for that. When I mentions "cell", I do mean the code cell in your link. As explained, I don't want to use code cell since it's not pure Python (i.e. Spyder specific) and reduces portability.

Comment: If you use `#%%` It is pure python. Your script will be runnable using `python script.py`. It is a special functionality of spyder. Lines starting with `#` are comment in regular python.

Comment: I would like to use the same feature and using cells does not solve the problem. I'll post a request on github and see what the developers say..

Comment: It's making progress there. The developer is willed to implement such a feature in the next version of Spyder!

Comment: I read the issue on github. Great!! I think the functionality is already there (`#%%`) but if this way doesn't fit in your workflow and the Spyder developers are so kind all is great!!!